# Access and run PHP project from Linux partition through WSL

Tags: linux, php, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I'm working on a PHP project in an Ubuntu 18.04 dual booted with Windows, I've been doing that for around 2 years, however, I'm needing windows quite a lot now in my studies for things like Excel, PowerBI, MiniTab...etc, these softwares are only available on windows, and I don't want to restart my laptop everytime. I tried Wine on Ubuntu but it didn't work well at all.

What I would love, is to access my project in the dual booted Ubuntu which is in an ext4 partition and also use the PHP setup I have on ubuntu directly from windows. I discovered WSL, but since I'm not a windows expert, I don't know if this is possible to achieve ?

Comment: Install [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)

Comment: Can I access the dual booted ubuntu from virtual box without having to download a new ubuntu image and reinstalling everything ?

Answer (score 0):

Mounting Linux filesystems is **not yet supported by WSL**, but will be supported by WSL2 in the future and is available on Windows Insider starting with build 20211. Do note that there is currently a limitation of only being able to mount drives and not individual partitions, though this might get lifted by the time this goes to the stable release of Windows.

Unless you are willing to run the insiders build of Windows (which I don't recommend) you're gonna have to wait until this version of WSL2 becomes available to the general public.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/access-linux-filesystems-in-windows-and-wsl-2/
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-mount-disk